# Result Set to text file using java

Tags: java, jdbc, text-files, resultset

I have used this code to write ResultSet to a text file.

```
FileWriter fstream = new FileWriter(new File("work/data/NewFile.txt"));   
BufferedWriter out = new BufferedWriter(fstream); 

 while(rs1.next()){
    String td_status=rs1.getString("td_status");
    int count=rs1.getInt("count(1)");

    System.out.println(td_status + "\t" +count );       
    out.write(rs1.getString("td_status"));   
    out.write(rs1.getInt("count(1)")); 
    out.newLine();              
}        
out.close();
```

in The text file it is written as

Success? Exempted by Range 0.1-0.0001 Rule  Exempted by lessthan 0.0001 Rule

But the actual ResultSet is

Success 153

Exempted by Range 0.1-0.0001 Rule 2

Exempted by lessthan 0.0001 Rule 3

Please can you help me in getting this?

Comment: You've possibly given incomplete code... Can you post rest of the program here? And what do you want to achieve with this? Very confusing question BTW..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is not with the ResultSet but with the usage of the FileWriter.

You are calling FileWriter.write(int), which is inherited from [OutputStreamWriter.write(int)](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/OutputStreamWriter.html#write(int)).  This method writes out a character, not a number.  Calling `out.write(153)` writes character 153 to the output.  It does not write the string `"153"`, which is what I imagine you want.

It does seem odd that a method that writes a character out has an `int` argument.  I'm not aware of the reason why - perhaps it's for symmetry with the `Reader.read()` method which reads a single character, returning it as an `int`, but with -1 specifying end-of-file.  This is somewhat inconsistent with  `System.out.println(int)`, which does print out an integer, and, as you have found out, unintuitive as well.

Replace the line

```
    out.write(rs1.getInt("count(1)"));
```

with

```
    out.write(Integer.toString(rs1.getInt("count(1)")));
```

and make any similar changes to any other calls to `out.write` that pass an `int` argument.

**EDIT**: if you want to insert line breaks, insert a line such as

```
    out.write(System.getProperty("line.separator"));
```

Alternatively, wrap the FileWriter in a BufferedWriter and use the [newLine()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/BufferedWriter.html#newLine()) method of that.

Comment: thank you. I also wanted to know how to get the result line by line. As in
Success 153 

Exempted by Range 0.1-0.0001 Rule 2

Exempted by lessthan 0.0001 Rule 3